# Adjust array by normalizing // functions

Tags: c++

working on this problem and having trouble figuring out what's wrong.

> The 5 indicates that there are five values in the list, namely 30, 50,
>   10, 70, and 65. 10 is the smallest value in the list, so is subtracted
>   from each value in the list.
>
> Input:5 30 50 10 70 65
>
> My output:20 40 0 70 65
>
> Expected output: 20 40 0 60 55

my code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int MAX_ELEMENTS = 20;
int GetMinimumInt(int listInts[], int numVals);

int main() {
  cin >> MAX_ELEMENTS;
  int userVals[MAX_ELEMENTS];
  int i;

  // populating the variable
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_ELEMENTS; ++i) {
    cin >> userVals[i];
  }

  // output values
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_ELEMENTS; ++i) {
    cout << userVals[i] - GetMinimumInt(&userVals[i], MAX_ELEMENTS) << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
int GetMinimumInt(int listInts[], int numVals) {
  int minValFun = listInts[1];  // smallest so far

  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ELEMENTS; ++i) {
    if (listInts[i] < minValFun) {
      minValFun = listInts[i];
    }
  }
  return minValFun;
}
```

Comment: `int userVals[MAX_ELEMENTS];` - variable-length arrays are not standard C++.  You should use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: @0x5453 I can only use arrays for this problem. Haven't gotten into vectors yet.

Comment: Then `int* userVals = new int[MAX_ELEMENTS];` is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out-of-range access will happen in `GetMinimumInt` because its argument is wrong.

You won't have to make offset for the array: You should use `GetMinimumInt(userVals, MAX_ELEMENTS)` instead of `GetMinimumInt(&userVals[i], MAX_ELEMENTS)`.

Also

```
int minValFun = listInts[1]; // smallest so far
```

in the function `GetMinimumInt` should be

```
int minValFun = listInts[0]; // smallest so far
```

to support 1-element array.